# HTML/Javascript - username and password

Tags: javascript, html

This html code below is suppose to execute and launch an alert asking for a username and if you get the username correct than it will ask for a password but nothing happens if i open this page in a browser. Why this doing this? What am I missing?  Please don't tell me this is a unsecure way to do this I already know I'm just improvising until I implant a better way.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var username;
var user1="grant"
username=prompt('Please Log in. Username:',' ');
if (username=user1);
   var pass1="password";
   password=prompt('If you are suppose to be here you have a password. Please type                  it now:',' ');
    if (password==pass1);
    else {
        window.location="wrongpassword.html";
    }
else {
  window.location="wrongpassword.html";
}
</script>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: `if (username=user1);` Really? ... single `=`, `;` after if expression, and no curly braces?

Comment: Also the `language` attribute on the `script` tag is deprecated. Use `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: Please clarify who you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some braces. Corrected code (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RyjhP/1/):

```
var user1="grant";
var username=prompt('Please Log in. Username:',' ');
if (username==user1){
   var pass1="password";
   password=prompt('If you are suppose to be here you have a password. Please type                  it now:',' ');
    if (password==pass1){
        alert("correct!")
     }
    else {
        window.location="wrongpassword.html";
    }
}
else {
  window.location="wrongpassword.html";
}
```

Comment: `if (username=user1)`

Answer (score 2):

short way to do that.

js

```
window.onload=function(){
window.location=prompt('Enter Pass')!='password'?'wrong.html':'ok.html'
}
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/6KzDJ/

but this is a very bad thing.

you should check the password from a secure location with ajax.